# Text box control & Moving to another form

Tags: excel, vba, controls, userform

I have two forms. The first form have text fields which should be filled by the user before proceeding to next form to fill. Below is my code. The code gives me an error. When ever I click the command button to close the form 1 and begin form 2.

If the fields in User Form 1 are not filled it should not take the user to Form 2.

```
Private Sub NexFinInfo_Click()

     If CLN.Text = "" Then

    MsgBox ("Company Legal Name is a mandatory field!")

Else

    Range("A2").Value = CLN.Text

End If

If BRL.Text = "" Then

    MsgBox ("Business Registration/ License is a mandatory field!")

Else

    Range("B2").Value = BRL.Text

End If

If COA.Text = "" Then

    MsgBox ("Company Address is a mandatory field!")

Else

    Range("C2").Value = COA.Text

End If

Range("D2").Value = PON.Text

Range("E2").Value = TNR.Text

If BLA.Text = "" Then

    MsgBox ("Billing Address is a mandatory field!")

Else

    Range("F2").Value = BLA.Text

End If

If Range("A2:C3", "F2").Value = "" And  Then

    MsgBox ("All the fields marked with * in the form are mandatory")

Else

    Unload Me

    FININFO.Show

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: It is better to simply use `Exit sub` after each `msgbox` . and also delete the if branch `If Range("A2:C3", "F2").Value = "" And  Then` Pl check its syntax, it is giving error. Instead may also check `PON` and `TNR` text

Comment: @AhmedAU Thanks! Now I get one msg box at a time. Can you please help me with this second problem in the code. I don't want the user to be prompted to the 2nd user form until all the text boxes in the userform 1 are filled. Appreciate your help in this matter.

Comment: @AhmedAU, Thanks I have tested the form. You have solved my problem! :)